# How can I embed a textarea inside of another textarea in HTML?

Tags: html

Is there a way to embed a textarea block inside of another textarea block but not render the inside textarea and preserve the outside textarea? I cannot modify the inside textarea. Perhaps there is something better to use for the outside block than a textarea. I need something that will submit its contents at POST. Converting the inside angle brackets to entities is *not* an option since I want to preserve the html inside the outer textarea.

Non-working Sample Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Embedded textareas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <textarea>
            Outside Textarea
            <textarea>Inside Textarea</textarea>
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I am creating an html form that is used to edit html code inside a textarea. The textareas inside break my form.

Comment: Can't you use tabs like wordpress editor ???

Comment: Do you mean you want the text "<textarea>...</textarea>" rendered inside of a textarea tag or are you oh dear my head just exploded.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. I am trying to edit html code inside an html textarea. I am editing html inside a textarea inside of an html form. *head explodes*

Comment: by styling? http://thetechawesomeness.ideasmatter.info/rapid-text-area-prototype.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yo dawg.

Seriously, encoding the html **is** the only option. You can always decode it/do whatever in your server-side code once it gets posted.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Embedded textareas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <textarea>
            Outside Textarea
            &lt;textarea&gt;Inside Textarea&lt;/textarea&gt;
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I heard you like textareas, so I put a textarea in your textarea so you can edit your textarea while you edit your textarea?

Comment: You must convert to entities.  The only other (ick) solution might be to use JavaScript to convert the brackets and populate the text area, and then reconvert on submit.

Answer (score 3):

I've have adequate success wrapping the textarea in a paragraph tag. These one worked for me:

```
<p style="margin:0;"><textarea rows="1" readonly="readonly" id="summary" name="Summary" ></textarea></p>

<p><textarea name="Note"></textarea></p>
```

This one didn't work for me:

```
<p><textarea rows="4" name="In_Honor_Address" class="blockInput"></textarea></p>
```

Haven't figured out what the difference is between one of these working and the other not, but worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You can't do it.  The only thing valid inside of a textarea is text.  It's a textarea. :-)

Comment: I only want to put text in my textarea, specifically the text </textarea>, but it won't let me do it!

Comment: No, you're trying to put the text &lt;/textarea&gt; in your text area. Excluding those entities are what encoding is for.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Embedded textareas</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
    #outside { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:0; width:400px;
        height:400px }
    #inside  { position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; z-index:1; 
        width:200px; height:200px; }
</style>

<body>

    <div>

        <textarea id="outside" rows="10" cols="80">
            Outside Textarea
        </textarea>

        <textarea id="inside" rows="5" cols="60" readonly>
            Inside Textarea
        </textarea>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well done but no good, inner textarea must be inside outer block and cannot modify inner textarea

Comment: because of http://thetechawesomeness.ideasmatter.info/rapid-text-area-prototype.html

Answer (score 1):

Heres your solution:

Replace all <'s and >'s with

```
&lt; and &gt;
```

Comment: This is incorrect as per the comments on the question indicate that he actually wants a fully functional `textarea` inside another `textarea`

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this, as i edit my templates via a textare on my site I want to of course have a textarea on the site....

My solution, when showing the text in the textarea for editing i do a string replace of /textaerea to /textarea placeholder, then before updating the database on submit i simply do the reverse, so either /textarea or /textarea placeholder will be correct and will show everything in the editor instead of closing the editor at the first occurrence of /textarea in the well, "text"

Also showing html entities really takes away from the editing of html, that is the reason i went with the replacement method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Embedded textareas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>
        Outside Textarea

    </textarea>
<textarea style="margin-top:-250px; height:250px;">Inside Textarea</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: didn't work for me in FF 3.5. Also, I forgot to mention that I don't want to modify the inside textarea. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hidden form field.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [FckEditor](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS293US304&q=FckEditor+download&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)?

Comment: Yes I have considered using an editor like FckEditor but I don't want a WYSIWYG editor. I just want a plain old text editor inside of an HTML textarea. I am using EditArea Javascript to style the html code though. Check it out here: http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and after searching high and low over the net for an answer i resolved it by putting the inside form into a seamless iframe.