# Getting raw HTML Textarea within other rextarea (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am getting raw html from my controller and getting it into textarea. there is different type of fields as **text select or also can be textarea** which will be print in textbox as raw html. its working fine for all fields except textarea.

when there is a field include with textarea type then below buttons string code not comes in text box and code of textarea type shows but **without ending tag as**

here is my code.

```
 foreach($fields as $field){
    $type = $field->type;
switch($type) {
   case 'textarea':
    $str .=    '<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">'.$custom_field->name.'
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-icon right">
                            <i class="fa"></i>
                            <textarea name="'.$field->id.'" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            break;
      }
}
```

Now every thing works fine except when textarea type included.
problem is if there is textarea type then below buttons not appear and also not ending tag of textarea

this end of html out put is as without buttons sting and without endtag

```
`<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Description
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="input-icon right">
                                <i class="fa"></i>
                                <textarea name="17" class="form-control" rows="8">`
```

please help where its wrong

Comment: Have you check the HTML it is generating?  View the source of the page and show what it's generating around that text area field.

Comment: Oh - and the idea of generating HTML in your controller is entirely wrong!  This is the Controller, HTML should be in the View - that's why they are called that, not just for convenience.

Comment: yes html is generating i am getting both form and raw html . form appears fine but issue in raw html @NigelRen

Comment: @bluemoon Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1638832/4771277

Comment: @Autista_z its a different. here in my case its work when i have only one type textarea when any other also added its give the issue

Comment: @bluemoon Yea, but i think, that this is problem. It ends parent textarea by using </textarea> in your Raw code. If you use input or select, it does not end parent textarea. But if you use encoded chars, it should not end it. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/dfjkwzye/

Comment: @bluemoon you are welcome. I wrote it as Answer as well, just accept it, so other people with same problem can find solution too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144033/discussion-between-blue-moon-and-autista-z).

Comment: why generating html inside controller? why not use the power of laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`

Everything else is OK.

Just edit your case to:

```
case 'textarea':
$str .=    '<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">'.$custom_field->name.'
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="input-icon right">
                        <i class="fa"></i>
                        <textarea name="'.$field->id.'" class="form-control" rows="8">&lt;/textarea&gt;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        break;
```